# OData entity relationships

Tags: odata

New to OData and running across a problem I could use some help with. Have two entities, Customer and Order. Customer has a complex property (Phone) which is all working great. But, when I add an order with a valid customer object, it gets inserted in the DB with a NULL value for customer.

Wondering what I am missing, any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks.

Classes are basically:

```
public class Customer
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public Phone Phone1 {get;set;}
   ...
}
public class Phone
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Number {get;set;}
   ...
}
public class Order
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public Customer Customer {get;set;}
   ...
}

In my WebApiConfig
            builder.EntitySet<Customer>("Customers");
            builder.EntitySet<Order>("Orders");
            builder.ComplexType<Phone>();

The metadata for order looks like this:
<EntityType Name="Order">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="Id"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="Updated" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Nullable="false"/>
...
<NavigationProperty Name="Customer" Type="Project.Common.Models.Customer"/>
</EntityType>
```

Comment: While the client is setting the proper customer object, in the controller the value in the order object for a customer is null.

Comment: I also just noticed that the phone objects, while being populated in the DB are correct, the values are null when returned to the client. So I am missing something major here. Thanks.